# Rspec & FactoryGirl: Is it really assigning the user id to my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails, shoulda

Here are my Factories:

**spec/factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username   'user1'
    time_zone  'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
    email      'user@example.com'
    password   'testing'
  end

  factory :product do
    name 'Great Product'
    about 'this is stuff about the product'
    private false
  end
end
```

My Product Model:

**models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :about, :name, :private
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :prices
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :user_id
end
```

This is my test using Rspec and [Shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) for help:

**spec/models/product_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Product do
  before(:each) do
    FactoryGirl.build(:product)
  end

  it { should have_many(:prices) }
  it { should belong_to(:user) }

  it { should validate_presence_of :name }
  it { should validate_presence_of :user_id }
end
```

The test passes but I thought I was suppose to do this for the association:

```
factory :product do
    name 'Great Product'
    about 'this is stuff about the product'
    private false

    user # <--
end
```

All the test will faill if I do this with the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Time zone is not included in the list
```

So is it really assigning the user that I created in the factory?

Edit

**User.rb**

```
  has_many :products

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_presence_of :time_zone
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3})[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
  validates_uniqueness_of :email         
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false
  validates_length_of :username, :within => 3..26
  validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones
```

Comment: What if you remove name, is it working

Comment: What if you remove name, is it working, can you test it using FactoryGirl.create(:product).

Comment: Rspec matchers `have_many` and `belong_to` verify that association is defined on the model. Nothing less nothing more. Don't know about `validate_presence_of` - where this comes from? Shoulda?

Comment: @ArtShayderov Yeah I believe so.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I tried both ways and it still gives me the same error about the Time zone.

Comment: @ArtShayderov, i think rspec does validates presence of if specified in model, since we wrote testcases for that.

Comment: Can you show your user model validations?

Comment: @LearningRoR Thank you. Here is the answer. 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation fails cause of wrong timezone you use in factories

```
1.9.3p194 :009 > ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones
=> [(GMT-10:00) Hawaii, (GMT-09:00) Alaska, (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada), (GMT-07:00) Arizona, (GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada), (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada), (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada), (GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)]

1.9.3p194 :010 > ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.include?('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> false
```

You should use in your factory something like

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
```

if you want your validation to pass.

Or if you want to store timezone in string value in database, you should change your code to something like this

```
# user.rb
...
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s)

# spec/factories.rb
...
time_zone  "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
...
```

Comment: I'm pretty knew to FactoryGirl, not sure how I would include it. Where does this go?

Comment: Just include `time_zone  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")` instead of `time_zone  'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:product)
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::Error: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)`

Comment: This error caused by your try to save ActiveSupport::TimeZone object to database. May be better way is to save only UTC offset there. Or use `Proc` in validation.

Comment: Or one more solution. You can validate inclusion of `time_zone` in array of strings with humanized timezone names. You can get this array with `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:to_s)`

Comment: So I can't set a time zone for the user? Right now I'm stuck at getting my factory to work. It works when I test with the User model but outside of that, it doesn't. I have a method to create the user and login for Capybara and throws me the error: Validation failed: `Time zone is not included in the list` even if I use `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)`

Comment: Of cause you can. You just have to decide in which format you want to do it. Right now you have conflict in storing it in string value like `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)` and your validation of inclusion in array `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones`. This array contains not string values, but `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` objects. That is the problem.

Comment: Well my database (postgresql) stores it in string like: `Eastern Time (US & Canada)` so that's why I did it that way. I just want to it to past and recognize the Time zone. I doesn't matter to me what it looks like.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I've updated answer. Try out last solution.

Comment: Well at least the error is different: `ArgumentError: Invalid Timezone: (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)`. I'll rewind and make another question based off this validation and than come back to this one. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Post this for others, the real answer is here but it was the time zone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361245/factorygirl-validation-failed-time-zone-is-not-included-in-the-list

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
  it { should validate_presence_of :user_id }
```

shoulda verifies that when `user_id` is missing your model isn't valid and that the list of errors contains an error for user_id with the appropriate message. Whether the object is initially valid (or has errors on other attributes) is irrelevant: this is why your test passes when your factory isn't assigning a user to the product

I suspect your other test fails because you are testing for the inclusion of a string (`time_zone`) in an array of timezone objects - `'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` is not equal to the corresponding time zone object (much like `"1" != 1`)